# using of EXISTS and NOT EXISTS In multiple columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table
`lock_keys_add` that I need to migrate its data to `lock_keys`

`lock_keys_add` has composite keys. So there could be multiple `lock_id` and `key_id` but it has unique constraint on `lock_id` and `key_id`

I have this query that would update the existing `lock_key` data if the combination already exists and insert new data if it does not.
The subquery returns 12 rows but it updates 320 rows (I believe there's something wrong with my exists part? I think it checks every entity individually and not the combination of both `lock_id` and `key_id` :(
How do I check both columns?

Here are my queries

```
UPDATE lock_keys
SET pending_status = 'Normal', action = 'Add'
FROM lock_keys lockKeys
WHERE EXISTS (select lockKeysAdd.lock_id, lockKeysAdd.key_id 
              FROM lock_keys_add AS lockKeysAdd
              WHERE lockKeys.lock_id = lockKeysAdd.lock_id and lockKeys.key_id = lockKeysAdd.key_id);


INSERT INTO lock_keys (pending_status, action, lock_id, key_id)
SELECT 'Normal', 'Add', lock_id, key_id 
FROM lock_keys_add lockKeysAdd 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT lock_id, key_id 
                  FROM lock_keys lockKeys 
                  WHERE lockKeys.lock_id = lockKeysAdd.lock_id
                 AND lockKeys.key_id = lockKeysAdd.key_id);
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Your first query certainly does not do what you intend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would not use a `FROM` in the `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE lock_keys lk
    SET pending_status = 'Normal',
        action = 'Add'
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM lock_keys_add lka
              WHERE lk.lock_id = lka.lock_id and lk.key_id = lka.key_id
             );
```

The `FROM` in an `UPDATE` in Postgres is a *separate* reference to the table.  So your query is doing a self-`CROSS JOIN`.

Comment: I also updated my insert column, it's now inserting the right columns :) I changed the `select 1` part

Comment: @mengmeng . . . Actually, what you select in the `exists` clause is not important.  I use `select 1` for two reasons.  It is easy to type.  And newer users of SQL might get confused if the value is `NULL` (it still passes the `EXISTS` test which counts *rows* not the values in the rows).

Comment: I'm with the "new users of sql" haha. Oh. Thanks for the information sir :) my update and insert statements are now working.